# Rails show action being called instead of update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that I need to submit to an "update" action in a controller. The "show" action is being called instead and the "update" action is never run.

My routes:

> ```
>        evaluations GET    /evaluations(.:format)              evaluations#index
>                    POST   /evaluations(.:format)              evaluations#create
>     new_evaluation GET    /evaluations/new(.:format)          evaluations#new
>    edit_evaluation GET    /evaluations/:id/edit(.:format)     evaluations#edit
>         evaluation GET    /evaluations/:id(.:format)          evaluations#show
>                    PATCH  /evaluations/:id(.:format)          evaluations#update
>                    PUT    /evaluations/:id(.:format)          evaluations#update
>                    DELETE /evaluations/:id(.:format)          evaluations#destroy
> ```

The form is created by:

```js
action: "<%= evaluation_path %>",
method: "patch" //I have tried both "post" and "put" as well
```

My controller has a valid "update" action as well.

Comment: The form is rendered from a Javascript object that is passed to a React Component.

Comment: Please show us the entire form code, at least the form_for or form_tag.

Comment: There is no form_for tag. The form is created by passing a Javascript object to a React Component which then sets the action and method.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

you should not forget to pass `id` or `record`, like follows:

```
action: evaluation_path(@evaluation), method: "patch"
```

also the way to avoid `action` key:

```
button_to "Update", evaluation_path(@evaluation), method: "patch"
```

Comment: @cmwall upadted answer

Answer (score 1):

Try the method `PATCH` in capital letters. Just a hunch. The HTTP verbs are often case-sensitive and are meant to be in upper-case.